# Why you can't install software offline in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why does Linux (desktop) does not provide a feature to just download a software and double click on it to install it like Windows does. It is annoying that you have to install all of your software online.

Is it technically impossible or is it just a design decision?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't? What do you think the package manager does? (Hint: the package manager, when asked to install some piece of software, downloads all packages required for the installation of the requested software, and then installs them in the correct order to satisfy dependencies.) You can go to Ubuntu's web site and download package files for whichever package you like, and install it locally. You lose out on a lot of the convenience of automatic dependency resolution, however. Then there are other options, like for example `apt-offline` and synaptic download scripts.

Comment: Who said that's the only way ? Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/321954/252822)

Comment: You could just download the package then install it offline, but using the package manager makes sure you always have the latest version of the software.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Why can't I for example just download VLC Media PLayer as one file and double click on it to install it like in Windows, why do I have to download all of the "packages required for the installation", why can't it be just one file?!

Comment: -1 From me. A question based on false assumptions, and a discussion in which there is no real desire to listen. Not the best atttude in a forum.

Comment: The only way you can install software offline in Ubuntu (and other Linux distros I guess) is if you jump through hoops (like you said, you can't just download a single file and double click on it to install, you have to download the software file itself and all of its dependencies!).

Answer (score 3):

First, as mentioned, your assumption is wrong: you *can* install software offline in Ubuntu, or any other Linux variant that I know of. (Edge cases may exist, but not to my knowledge.)

The proper question is either "why shouldn't I ... ?" or "why isn't the vlc package for Ubuntu complete?" Both depend on the basics behind the other. So, lets start with what the situation is.

When you get a package to install in Windows it includes *everything* needed to install that package: drivers, subsystems, supporting libraries (DLLs), etc. When you run the installer it looks at the system to see what's needed and what's not, hopefully only installing the ones needed, and not overwriting any similar files used by other packages. Since everything needed is included, one download does it all. If your system doesn't have the MP3 codec VLC expects installed, then the one included in the downloaded package is installed. Even if you have a different MP3 codec, that VLC isn't written to use, you still get the other one from VLC's installer.

When you get a package to install in Linux, it includes that program exclusively. None of the other things it might need are included. If VLC player needs an MP3 codec installed, then you have to install that as well, or VLC won't play MP3 files. The same applies to any other dependencies that the package might list.

If you do the proper research, such as checking package dependencies, you *can* download the `.deb` files (for Ubuntu, or `.rpm` files for RedHat) and then install all the needed packages offline. It is a lot of work, and if you miss something you have to go back and download that and install it. Once you are done, it still works, and it was all installed offline.

All that work is what the package manager for a distribution takes care of for you. **If** you needed to install *every* dependency for that package, you have to download all of them first. In Windows, if you want to install a package, you also have to download all of its dependencies before you install it as well. The difference is that the Windows installer has bundled all those dependencies into a single downloaded file, while Linux has each package in it's own file.

Now, what happens if you install five different media players in Windows? Almost all the media players will need the same basic set of libraries in the system, such as an MP3 codec, an interface to the sound system, an interface to the window manager, and a way to read files from the filesystem, etc. If you install VLC first, it will install all those helpers, since nothing else has installed them yet. Then, when you install Banshee, most of the helper files are already installed. Therefore, the installer has very little to do except find them and create the links to them for that program. By the time you've installed the last player, whatever it is, there's a very good chance that every helper file needed is already there, and installation goes real fast.

What happens if you install five media players in Linux? Pretty much the same thing. If you use the package manager, and watch as it progresses, you'll even see the long list of helper files installed with the first player, a much shorter list with the second one, and probably none on the fifth one.

So, what's the difference? None, right? **Wrong.** All five Windows installers will hold all the helper files. So you will have downloaded five copies of the MP3 codec, five copies of the WMA codec, 5 copies of the FLAC codec, five copies of the window manager interface, etc., and etc. In Linux, on the other hand, you will have downloaded one copy of each helper file, not five, and your bandwidth usage will be smaller. If you save the installers for later, then you also have much less disk space used. In addition, many of the helper files may already be installed, so you won't have downloaded, or saved, any of those.

Looking at two packages that have a Unundu `.deb` and a Windows `.exe` or `.msi` to compare head-to-head, we get:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 gypsy users 23052120 May 11 22:35 Banshee-2.4.0.msi
-rw-r--r-- 1 gypsy users 30533688 May 11 21:49 vlc-2.2.4-win32.exe
                         --------
                 Total = 53585808
-rw-r--r-- 1 gypsy users  2731866 May 11 22:36 banshee_2.9.0+really2.6.2-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 gypsy users  2002764 May 11 21:52 vlc_2.2.4-4_amd64.deb
                         --------
                 Total =  4734630
```

Comparing the sizes of the packages for those two players, it's about ten times as much downloaded for Windows over Linux. Obviously some programs will be even worse, and others will be better. For example, to install Perl, using Strawberry Perl, on Windows, I download an 84.3 MB `.msi` file. To install in Linux I can download the source at 15.6 MB, which is only one-fifth the size.

Why the differences? Mostly because of philosophy. In the [Linux philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), which was inherited from Unix, is the concept of *do one thing, and do it well.* So the installer for a package doesn't have to know how to install, and link, and test, all of the helper libraries it needs, only check if they are where they are supposed to be. Firefox's installer doesn't have to install OpenSSL to check website certificates for HTTPS, it only has to know that it has, or does not have, access to it.

Another part of Linux philosophy is choice. That's part of why there are so many distributions of Linux to choose from, and why you can install so many different window managers, and other programs. You can also choose which MP3 codec you want to use, and there are both Open Source and Proprietary versions to choose from.

All that being said, there are a few cases where someone has created a bundle to install, in one step, some package or other. One that comes to mind right away is [Mail-in-a-Box](https://mailinabox.email/). Even that, however, still needs to installed online, since it will do what a package manager does in looking for, and downloading as needed, the other libraries that make it work. It still does not "bundle" everything into one download.

### The Bottom Line

If you *must* install offline, use the package manager to do the sorting, sifting and selecting for you. Just tell it not to install the files, only download them. Then you can go offline and do the install yourself. If you want to get more adventuristic in your installs, download the original source tarballs and compile the packages. You'll probably get a better performance as a bonus. You can use the saved disk space for more music, videos, and games, if you like. To really go onto the "Wild Side," try creating your own Linux from the ground up, including compiling the kernel itself. [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) is such a project, will all the steps worked out for you. But, do this on a spare computer, since it will **not** be an overnight install, and once done, you will still have to do even more to get back the the windowed GUI that you are used to.

Comment: It's always nice when a bad question gets good answers.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "why doesn't Linux provide this feature" is [mu](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html).

> a Japanese word alleged to mean “Your question cannot be answered because it depends on incorrect assumptions”.

To justify this unusual answer:

Since long time ago in various flavors of Linux you have been able to download and install packages by yourself (or to build from sources) or to use some kind of manager. The latter is new in Windows world. If any system makes you have to install in one way, not another, certainly it is not Linux.

Comment: So basically as a regular user I can't just download a software that consist of one file (like for example "VLC Media PLayer.exe" in Windows) and double click on it to install. No, I have to jump through hoops to do a simple task such as this.

Comment: @user608991 You can download a packet, e.g. Vivaldi browser as a `deb` [from here](https://vivaldi.com/download/). Packet manager in Ubuntu should install it after a double click. Still you need root privileges and this is a good thing for security and administrative reasons. With only regular user's privileges you can use standalone version of software or some non-systemwide installer, if available -- both are rather not common. It all depends on your system configuration, permissions etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. A repository you use for installing software is often nothing (much) more than a ftp/http server providing packages as files. In case of Debian-based distributions these are .deb files. You could download these and install them offline.

Often the package-manager even provides an option to "download-only".

Usually you use the package-manager online as this way it handles dependencies (programs/libraries that need to be installed in order for the actual wanted program to work) and checks for signatures so that no-one can provide you with modified, possibly malicious, packages.