# Ubuntu/Debian/Raspberry Pi OS based standalone offline installer to include dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, raspberry-pi, package-management

I'm looking at ways to create an installers for a C++ binary (but could be any other software in future) to include dependencies such that the installer can be run standalone and offline by an end user as there are some scenarios where the software needs to be installed in remote locations without an internet connection.
Installers are needed for Raspberry Pi OS and Ubuntu (both Debian based distributions) desktop installations running Gnome.
[Most questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1092122/why-you-cant-install-software-offline-in-linux) on stackexchange relating to installing packages offline for Debian based distributions assume some prior knowledge of what is already installed on the target operating system (or the ability to find out what packages are required) and suggest producing a list of the missing packages (`sudo apt install --dry-run <package>`), then download (`apt download`) from a machine with internet access then transfer to the target machine to install, however the purpose of this question is to determine the options when nothing is known about the target machine other than the operating system major version.

The following is an example list of dependencies:

```
ladspa-sdk
libasound2-dev
libcurl4-openssl-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libglu1-mesa-dev
libjack-jackd2-dev
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev
libx11-dev
libxcomposite-dev
libxcursor-dev
libxcursor-dev
libxext-dev
libxinerama-dev
libxrandr-dev
libxrender-dev
mesa-common-dev
```

Using Raspberry Pi OS (Bullseye) as an example, with `raspios_arm64-2023-05-03` installed, running `sudo apt install --dry-run <dependencies>` without an internet connection results in a list of 98 packages that to be installed. If I then establish an internet connection to download those packages, some of them will fail the first time round because they have been superseded by a later version and no longer exist in the repository and the new version isn't picked up until `apt update` has run for the first time to refresh the list of available packages:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/curl/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.74.0-1.3%2bdeb11u7_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-dev_1.7.2-1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/webkit2gtk/gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0_2.38.5-1%7edeb11u1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/webkit2gtk/gir1.2-webkit2-4.0_2.38.5-1%7edeb11u1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/webkit2gtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev_2.38.5-1%7edeb11u1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/webkit2gtk/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev_2.38.5-1%7edeb11u1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:82::644 80]
```

After running `sudo apt update`, executing the same command picks up later versions of the same packages that failed above and the packages can then be downloaded using the same `apt download` command.

Regardless, the 98 packages downloaded on `raspios_arm64-2023-05-03` won't be the versions expected when trying to install with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` on an earlier Bullseye version of Raspberry Pi OS such as `raspios_arm64-2021-11-08` and doing so results in a lot of dependency errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev:arm64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglvnd-dev:arm64:
 libglvnd-dev:arm64 depends on libegl-dev (>= 1.3.0-1); however:
  Package libegl-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libglvnd-dev:arm64 depends on libgles-dev (>= 1.3.0-1); however:
  Package libgles-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglvnd-dev:arm64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglx-dev:arm64:
 libglx-dev:arm64 depends on libx11-dev; however:
  Package libx11-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglx-dev:arm64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libharfbuzz-dev:arm64:
 libharfbuzz-dev:arm64 depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.19.1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

...

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Without bundling the entire contents of the debian/raspbian mirrors and refreshing the apt package index against it, I can't see that there's a reliable way of being able to install the dependencies required using .deb packages for a standalone offline installer. Are there any other ideas here for using .deb packages to install the dependencies?

Alternative options I'm looking at are:

- AppImage
- Flatpak
- Snapcraft

However, both `snapd` and `flatpak` also require apt dependencies to install (albeit a much reduced set - which could be more manageable), but in addition to those, snaps (at least) also require a base image (e.g. core20, core22) in order to run.

The other idea I've been looking at is to extract shared objects from all of the dependency .deb files and bundle those as part of the installer to be extracted to a specific folder then using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/shared/objects/folder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ./binary` - this appears to work with some early experimentation but I haven't done extensive testing and wonder if this could be a bit fragile or if there could be dependency files (other than the .so files) that may be needed.

The appeal of Snapcraft is that it's backed by Canonical but it seems that AppImages may be the only reliable method of deployment that are intended to bundle everything required to run the application as a standalone executable (rather than an installer) - is this the case or has anyone solved this problem any other way?

Comment: You've got a lot going on here. My first question would be: what compiler or package builder are you using and does it have a function to include these? Second, those questions on SE are correct: Assuming EVERY dependency means you're building a docker image or full live OS build like Kali. You have to make SOME assumptions about what is on a "normal" instance of the OS you're targeting. Linux, especially, tends to vary more widely in its installs due to its very nature.

Comment: If all machines on which this is to be installed are the same, easiest by far: 1. Set up one machine as desired. 2. Make a drive image. 3. Restore that image to each new machine, i.e., cloning the origianl system.

Comment: @music2myear gcc/g++ for compiling, open to options regarding the installer depending on the most appropriate solution

Comment: @DrMoishePippik not an option unfortunately as any installer would need to be provided to end user/support teams to install remotely

Comment: Regarding assumptions, it is safe to assume the target host is running a desktop OS (Gnome) - I've updated the original post to include this additional information

Comment: @gratz, are all machines *identical* (same model, same size drive and RAM, etc.)? If so, then the image file *could* be installed by the appropriate utility. There is the extra room needed for the utility, which might be ~500 MB for some tools.